# Error in javascript KeyListener

Tags: javascript, html

I have the error: `index.html:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`
Not sure what went wrong? The code is suppose to store the result of the radio button selected into an array. But the function does not even run because it is null.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Video Test</title>
    <script>
      var arr = [];
      document.getElementById("continue").addEventListener("click", function() {
          var cbChecked = document.querySelectorAll('[name="white"]:checked')
          if (cbChecked != null) {
            arr.push(cbChecked.value)
          }
          console.log(arr)
      }) 
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="overlay">
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="white" value="1" id="radio1"/>
          <input type="radio" name="white" value="2" id="radio2"/>
          <input type="radio" name="white" value="3" id="radio3"/>
          <input type="radio" name="white" value="4" id="radio4"/>
          <input type="button" id="continue" value="Continue"/>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="base">
        <video controls>
          <source src="videos/event_0_Junli_Standing_20150322_181647_00_0.6.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try putting your script at the bottom, so the dom is rendered before the script, or else put the code in the ready event of the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running your `<script>` before the DOM elements are there.  Move the `<script>` to the bottom of the `<body>` tag.

Comment: Ahh ok that solved it!

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll` returns an array of objects, not a single object.

```js
var arr = [];
      document.getElementById("continue").addEventListener("click", function() {
          var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked')          
          if (radios.length > 0) {
            arr.push(radios[0].value)
          }
          console.log(arr)
      })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Video Test</title>
    <script>
   
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="overlay">
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="white" value="1" id="radio1"/>
          <input type="radio" name="white" value="2" id="radio2"/>
          <input type="radio" name="white" value="3" id="radio3"/>
          <input type="radio" name="white" value="4" id="radio4"/>
          <input type="button" id="continue" value="Continue"/>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="base">
        <video controls>
          <source src="videos/event_0_Junli_Standing_20150322_181647_00_0.6.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```